# How to pass smart pointer instead of "this" in C++ 11?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am using [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) compiler.

I have two classes - class `Test` and class `TestHelper`.
The class `Test` is a friend-to-class `TestHelper`.
The class `Test` is only which we can access from outside.

Now, we want to call `Test` API i.e. `setVal()`. This `setVal()` should call
`Test2` API i.e. setX and is expecting this pointer. I don't want to use this pointer but want
to use a smart pointer instead. How can I do so?

The notion of this kind of desirability is because of the fact that in reality, my class `Test` is pretty big. So, I am trying to make a helper class for `Test` i.e.

```
class TestHelper;

class Test
{
    friend class TestHelper;
    int x;
public:
    void display() {
        std::cout << x;
     }
    void setVal(int val) {
        TestHelper testH;
        testH.setX(this, 324);
    }
};

class TestHelper
{
public:
    void setX(Test *test, int val) {
        /** some algorithm here and then  change val to something else */
        test->x = val*100;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    Test x;
    x.setVal(130);
}
```

I tried changing the prototype from `void setX(Test *test, int val)`
to `void setX(std::shared_ptr<Test> test, int val)`  but don't know how to pass this pointer
as `std::shared_ptr<Test> test` here.

Comment: `I don't want to use this pointer but want to use a smart pointer instead. ` Why do you want this?

Comment: A shared pointer assumes ownership of the passed object. That means, that if the object is destroyed by any other means than 'the shared_pointer', bad things happen. In your code, you're statically allocating an instance of 'Test', meaning it will be destroyed upon leaving the scope, making the use of a shared_ptr fatal.

Comment: If you want to use smart pointers, std::shared_ptr is your only option. To get shared_ptr to this you must use shared_from_this. See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/shared_from_this

Comment: I think a reference to Test might be a better fit here (or in this specific case a return value for x). You may want to pass Test to the TestHelper in the constructor, so you can use it for more actions without passing this every time.

Comment: You have no reason at all to use smart_ptr here. Your Test class never take ownership of the class. You should use reference instead-

Answer (score 0):

So here is working solution with shared pointers. The example doesn't even compile due to missing definitions so you have to restructure your code into headers and cpp files.

**Test.h:**

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

#include <memory>
#include "TestHelper.h"

class Test : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Test>
{
    private:
        friend class TestHelper;
        int x;
    public:
        void display();
        void setVal(int val);
};

#endif
```

**Test.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Test.h"

void Test::display() {
    std::cout << x;
}

void Test::setVal(int val) {
    TestHelper testH;
    testH.setX(shared_from_this(), 324);
}
```

**TestHelper.h:**

```
#ifndef TESTHELPER_H
#define TESTHELPER_H

class Test;

class TestHelper
{
    public:
        void setX(std::shared_ptr<Test> test, int val);
};

#endif
```

**TestHelper.cpp:**

```
#include <memory>

#include "TestHelper.h"
#include "Test.h"

void TestHelper::setX(std::shared_ptr<Test> test, int val) {
    /** some algorithm here and then  change val to something else */
    test->x = val*100;
}
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

#include "Test.h"

int main(void){
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    auto x = std::make_shared<Test>();
    x->setVal(130);
    x->display();
}
```

You can run it here: https://paiza.io/projects/e/79dehCx0RRAG4so-sVZcQw

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you want this, here's a few variants that compile

reference

```
// Reference variant

#include <iostream>

class Test;

class TestHelper
{
    public:
    void setX(Test & test, int val);
};

class Test
{
    friend class TestHelper;
    int x;
public:
    void display() {
        std::cout << x;
     }
    void setVal(int val) {
        TestHelper testH;
        testH.setX(*this, 324);
    }
};

void TestHelper::setX(Test &test, int val) 
{
    /** some algorithm here and then  change val to something else */
    test.x = val*100;
}

int main()
{
    Test x;
    x.setVal(130);
    x.display();
}
```

http://cpp.sh/7t3ec

shared ptr

```
// Shared ptr variant

#include <iostream>

#include <memory> // Required for shared_ptrs

class Test;

class TestHelper
{
    public:
    void setX(std::shared_ptr<Test> test, int val);
};

class Test : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Test>
{
    friend class TestHelper;
    int x;
public:
    void display() {
        std::cout << x;
     }
    void setVal(int val) {
        TestHelper testH;
        testH.setX(shared_from_this(), 324);
    }
};

void TestHelper::setX(std::shared_ptr<Test> test, int val) 
{
    /** some algorithm here and then  change val to something else */
    test->x = val*100;
}

int main()
{
    auto x = std::make_shared<Test>(); // x needs to be created as shared_ptr or it won't work
    x->setVal(130);
    x->display();
}
```

http://cpp.sh/87ao2

Perhaps with these you can refine your question?